# Embed form in ArrayCollection Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, arraycollection

I have form:

[image]

My code to Tag1 look like:

```
$builder
        ->add('tag1', 'collection', [
            'type'   => 'text',
            'label' => 'Tag1',
            'allow_add'         => true,
            'allow_delete'      => true,
            'prototype'         => true,
            'options'           =>
                [
                    'required'  => false,
                    'label'     => false
                ]
        ])
```

But how add Sub form in field?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think it's quite simple.

```
$builder
    ->add('tag1', 'collection', [
        'type' => new yourSubFormType(),
        ...
    ])
```

more information : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html